# ParallelDo and Reap/Sow in combination fails

Tags: parallelization

I just realized the following problem. I tried to speed up a program that reads hundreds of files each of size up to 200+ MB and processes them, therefore I changed a `Do` to `ParallelDo` . The code (a part of the whole program) is as follows:

```
out = Reap[
   ParallelDo[
    data = Import[currentFile];
    data = Mean /@ (Through[data[#]] & /@ features);
    Sow[{getNumber[currentFile], data}] 
    {currentFile, files}]
   ];
```

This delivers an empty output. When changing back from `ParallelDo` to "normal" `Do` everything is fine. My conjecture is, that the `Reap`/ `Sow` mechanism gets "upset" here. Any other ideas?

Comment: In this simple case, `ParallelTable` should work. In general, I would suggest to create one list or association per kernel and merge them in the end.

Comment: I think it is because expressions are `Sow`ed in subkernels, which doesn't affect the state of the master kernel. So, in the master kernel, there is nothing to `Reap`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Yes, this could be a good approach! I used this in other programs -but here I didn't had this idea. This code is somewhat older so I got stuck with the `Reap`/ `Sow` construction. I rewrite this to `ParallelTable`- Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Anton.Sakovich I think you are right the sub kernels could be the problem. Thank you.

Comment: There are countless threads on this on this site. Parallel "threads" are really different processes, they don't share memory.